# How to create ref inside react hoc using typescript without forwardedRef

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-ref, react-hoc

This is my code:

```js
import React, {
  InputHTMLAttributes,
  Component,
  ComponentClass,
  TextareaHTMLAttributes
} from 'react';


// type TElementType = HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement;
// type TAttributesType =
//   | InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>
//   | TextareaHTMLAttributes<HTMLTextAreaElement>;

interface IClassType {
  somevalue: string;
}

type TElementType = HTMLInputElement;
type TAttributesType = InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>;

const withInput = (Comp: ComponentClass<TAttributesType>): ComponentClass<IClassType> => {
  class MyInput extends Component<IClassType> {
    private refValue = React.createRef<TElementType>();

    componentDidMount() {
      console.log('do something');
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <>
          <Comp
            name="someinput"
            value="somevalue"
            type="text"
            ref={ref => {
              this.refValue = ref;
            }}
          />
        </>
      );
    }
  }

  return MyInput;
};

export default withInput;
```

**This is the error on this.refValue = ref:**

> Type 'Component<TAttributesType, any, any> | null' is not assignable to type 'RefObject'.
> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'RefObject'.

I have looked online and can only find examples of forwardedRefs. I do not need to forward a ref from my passed component, since the ref is only necessary within my hoc.

Comment: I don't think this will resolve your issue (I'm not very familiar with typescript), but it appears you are mixing current and legacy ref syntax. With the current refs generated from `React.createRef` you simply attach the ref, i.e. `ref={this. refValue}`, to the component.

Comment: The typescript error is basically saying that you are mixing up the current value of the ref with the ref itself.  You would want to set this.refValue.current.  But @Drew is right that the other syntax is easier.